# How can I add new own authentication services in SecureSocial

Tags: playframework-2.0, oauth-2.0, securesocial

I'm trying to make a website with Play Framework (2.1.3) and would like to try to add authentication via SecureSocial.

SecureSocial website developer says: "Based on a modular architecture that allows you to add new authentication services". but I did not find any example of how you can add my own authentication module (OAuth).

I use JAVA as main language.

Can anyone describe the procedure of adding my own authentication module?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is easy to add new providers using Java, since the SecureSocial core is written in Scala.

To add your own provider, take a look at the source code of existing providers: https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/providers

You'll have to either extends `OAuth1Provider` or `OAuth2Provider`.